# TF249051: No URL can be found that corresponds to the following server name

Tags: excel-2007, add-in

So am trying to open work items in Excel on my machine (TFS 2010 and Excel 2007) and I received original error from Excel

```
TF80070: Team Foundation encountered an error while performing the operation.
```

I found instructions on how to turn on diagnostics to find the underlying cause which is the error in the title

```
TF249051: No URL can be found that corresponds to the following server name
```

I cannot find anywhere in Excel that I can tweak the settings. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution I found (after disabling and re-enabling the addin inside Excel and also removing the addin from inside Excel and re-adding it) was to go to the Team menu in Excel and click New List. It prompted me to connect to my collection which I did and then opened up a query (My Tasks). I guess somehow it didn't know exactly what to connect to although the complete error message I got from the diagnostic trace included the correct tfs server name and default collection name.